# SoftLayer Desktop VPN client

Tags: networking, vpn

I'm having an issue using SoftLayer's Desktop VPN client for Linux.

I've found that I am only able to successfully connect to my VPN secured services the first time I run the client. Every subsequent attempt to run the client seems to succeed, though I am unable to connect to my secured services.

Here's what I see when I run the client in the command line the first time after restarting my computer:

```
./array_vpnc -hostname vpn.dal01.softlayer.com -username XXX -passwd XXX
array_vpnc: VPN TUNNEL SUCCESSFUL!
```

After that first time, this is what I see after stopping the service and starting again:

```
./array_vpnc -hostname vpn.dal01.softlayer.com -username XXX -passwd XXX
SIOCADDRT: File exists
SIOCADDRT: File exists
array_vpnc: VPN TUNNEL SUCCESSFUL!
```

I have also noticed that my `/etc/resolv.conf` gets overwritten when running the client. I've been manually restoring it in order to be able to use the internet.

Here's what is written into `my resolv.conf` file:

```
nameserver 10.0.80.11
nameserver 10.0.80.12
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

My system specs:

```
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (a custom IBM version)
Memory: 7.6 GiB
Processor: Intel Core i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz x 4
OS Type: 32-bit
```

Answer (score 1):

So major face palm on this one...

I wasn't closing the first running of the vpn client. What I was doing was suspending it (hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>) when what I should have been doing was closing it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>).

It turns out that suspending a VPN connection and then starting another one will indeed mess with your network config and also fail to create a VPN connection.